# Brute Force in C for 3Sum - But how do I detect duplicate triplets?

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, brute-force

I am aware this is a brute force and non optimal approach to solving the 3Sum problem. It does the job of detecting the triplets which sum up to zero. But I am looking for ways to detect duplicate triplets. I am not able to come up with the logic to look for similar triplet combinations which have already been considered. Thanks!

```
int** threeSum(int* nums, int numsSize, int *returnSize) 
{
int count = 0;
int **res = NULL;
for (int i=0; i<(numsSize-2) ; i++)
{
    for (int j=i+1; j<(numsSize-1) ; j++)
    {
        for(int k=j+1; k<numsSize ; k++)
        {
            if (0==(nums[i]+nums[j]+nums[k]))
            {
                if (count > 0)
                {
                    res = (int **)realloc(res,sizeof(int *)*(count+1));
                    res[count] = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int)*3);
                    res[count][0] = nums[i];
                    res[count][1] = nums[j];
                    res[count][2] = nums[k];
                    count++;
                }
                else if (0==count)
                {
                    res = (int **) malloc(sizeof(int *)*1);
                    res[0] = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int)*3);
                    res[0][0] = nums[i];
                    res[0][1] = nums[j];
                    res[0][2] = nums[k];
                    count++;
                }
            }
        } 
    }
}
*returnSize=count;
if (count > 0)
return res;
else
return NULL;``
}
```

Comment: Basically I am looking for duplication detection logic which can fit into this brute force approach. Is it possible or do *I have to* create a hash table ?

Comment: Having `malloc()` in a loop like that and not checking if it returns `NULL` is dangerous. You can run out of memory some time. Also, `malloc()` is not for a compile time known size, it's for a runtime size. annoying and ugly very are Conditions Yoda And.

Comment: Perhaps if you sort the array first... duplicates will be easier to find.

Comment: Also, your code has too much nesting, avoid that write functions.

Comment: The loop controls could also be bounded by the requirement that at least 2 of the 3 terms must have opposite sign.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi  - Yes, I will incorporate the NULL check and minimize nesting. Also I used malloc / realloc combination since I do not know the number of triplets at compile time. Any other alternatives?

Comment: @WeatherVane - What if it was an array of 100 zeroes?

Comment: Oh come on. If you remove all the duplicates leaving the array with minimum length 3 . . .

Comment: @WeatherVane - Sorry! That was a dumb comment.

Comment: @WeatherVane: why did you delete your answer? It was easy to fix and provided good hints as to how to improve on the brute force approach. Sorry if I may have come across a bit rude, not intended at all and no intention to downvote useful answers.

Comment: @chqrlie because it was wrong. I suppose the easy fix would be to leave a mininum of *two* duplicates.

Comment: @WeatherVane: yes, and you can improve the speed with a binary search of `-(nums[i] + nums[j])` in `nums[j+1..terms-1]`

Comment: @chqrlie not so simple after all. When I allow two repeats such that `-4 -4 8` is found, then duplicate combinations are found, such as `-4 1 3` where there is a single `1, 3`. It's an [interesting question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM) though.

Comment: @WeatherVane - Can you elaborate on the above example [-4,-4,8] and [-4,1,3] ?

Comment: @Sunny I undeleted my answer, although I must say it is not right. I subsequently allowed two of each value to remain, so that `-4 -4 8` is not missed (where there were at least two of `-4` originally). But sadly, where there might have been a single instance of say `1` and `3` I now have a duplication of the triplet `-4 1 3` for each of the two `-4` elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your code as there are redundant blocks:

- `realloc` can be called with `NULL` and acts like `malloc`.
- returning `res` is OK when `count` is `0` as it was initialized to `NULL`.

You can check for duplicates, you can sort the triplet and search it in the list of matches before insertion, with brute force too:

```
int **threeSum(int *nums, int numsSize, int *returnSize) {
    int count = 0;
    int **res = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < numsSize - 2; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < numsSize - 1; j++) {
            for (int k = j + 1; k < numsSize; k++) {
                if (nums[i] + nums[j] + nums[k] == 0) {
                    int a = nums[i], b = nums[j], c = nums[k], n;
                    if (a > b) { int t = a; a = b; b = t; }
                    if (b > c) { int t = b; b = c; c = t; }
                    if (a > b) { int t = a; a = b; b = t; }
                    for (n = 0; n < count; n++) {
                        if (a == res[n][0] && b == res[n][1])
                            break;
                    }
                    if (n == count) {
                        int **p = realloc(res, sizeof(*p) * (count + 1));
                        int *p1 = malloc(sizeof(*p1) * 3);
                        if (p == NULL || p1 == NULL) {
                            for (n = 0; n < count; n++)
                                free(res[n]);
                            free(res);
                            free(p);
                            free(p1);
                            *returnSize = -1;
                            return NULL;
                        }
                        res = p;
                        p1[0] = a;
                        p1[1] = b;
                        p1[2] = c;
                        res[count] = p1;
                        count++;
                    }
                    break; // any other match would be a duplicate.
                }
            } 
        }
    }
    *returnSize = count;
    return res;
}
```

Notes:

- no need to test if `c == res[n][2]` because `res` only contains matches
- no need to test further elements for the same `i` and `j` after a match is found.

Comment: Thanks! This is precisely within the brute force paradigm where I was trying to find the solution (I stuck to brute force to get a better grip on pointers and arrays). The only minor change I made in the above code snippet was to change `int p1 = malloc(sizeof(*p1) * 3); ` to `int* p1 = malloc(sizeof(*p1) * 3);`

Comment: Also a side note - this solution exceeds the time limit (in LeetCode) but I goto learn what I set out to learn :)

Comment: @Sunny: good catch! If you have a time limit, it is worthwhile to try and reduce the complexity from the current biquadratic approach down to a quadratic method as explained in the wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM

Comment: Sure! Thanks. I will explore that solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** I deleted this incorrect answer, but now enabled it (although not updated from various comments, because it is still wrong).

For what it's worth I changed the duplicate removal to this:

```
int terms = 2;

// . . .

// remove duplicates
for(int i = 2; i < TERMS; i++) {
    if(nums[i] != nums[terms - 1] || nums[i] != nums[terms - 2]) {
        nums[terms++] = nums[i];
    }
}
```

---

First I sort the array, and then remove duplicates.
Optionally, I make early loop terminations when the 0 sum is impossible.

I have not created an array of solutions, only printed – I leave that to you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define TERMS   30      // length of array
#define MAXVAL  9       // value range + - MAXVAL
#define CHECK           // compiler option quit when 0 sum is impossible

int cmp(const void *a, const void *b) {
    return (*(int*)a) - (*(int*)b);
}

void show(char *legend, int *nums, int size)
{
    printf("%s\n", legend);
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%d ", nums[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}

int main(void) {

    int nums[TERMS];
    int terms = 1;
    int sum;
    int results = 0;

    // build array
    //srand((unsigned)time(NULL));        // comment out for repeatable values
    for(int i = 0; i < TERMS; i++) {
        nums[i] = rand() % (MAXVAL * 2 + 1) - MAXVAL;
    }
    show("input", nums, TERMS);

    // sort array
    qsort(nums, TERMS, sizeof nums[0], cmp);
    show("sorted", nums, TERMS);

    // remove duplicates
    for(int i = 1; i < TERMS; i++) {
        if(nums[i] != nums[terms - 1]) {
            nums[terms++] = nums[i];
        }
    }
    show("removed dups", nums, terms);

    // find triplets with 0 sum
    printf("zero sum triplets\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < terms; i++) {
#ifdef CHECK
        if(nums[i] > 0) {
            // early termination if impossible
            break;
        }
#endif
        for(int j = i + 1; j < terms; j++) {
            for(int k = terms-1; k > j; k--) {
#ifdef CHECK
                if(nums[k] < 0) {
                    // early termination if impossible
                    break;
                }
#endif
                sum = nums[i] + nums[j] + nums[k];
                if(sum == 0) {
                    printf("%4d %4d %4d\n", nums[i], nums[j], nums[k]);
                    results++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\n%d results\n", results);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output

```
input
-6 9 -2 5 8 2 -7 -6 -8 2 -4 -3 -3 3 -4 7 3 1 -8 -7 6 3 -2 -8 -2 4 8 -8 6 -7 

sorted
-8 -8 -8 -8 -7 -7 -7 -6 -6 -4 -4 -3 -3 -2 -2 -2 1 2 2 3 3 3 4 5 6 6 7 8 8 9 

removed dups
-8 -7 -6 -4 -3 -2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 

zero sum triplets
  -8    1    7
  -8    2    6
  -8    3    5
  -7   -2    9
  -7    1    6
  -7    2    5
  -7    3    4
  -6   -3    9
  -6   -2    8
  -6    1    5
  -6    2    4
  -4   -3    7
  -4   -2    6
  -4    1    3
  -3   -2    5
  -3    1    2

16 results
```

Comment: your compare function is incorrect: it has undefined behavior if the difference between 2 elements is outside the range of `int`.  Use `return (*(const int*)a) > (*(const int*)b) - (*(const int*)a) < (*(const int*)b);`

Comment: @chqrlie I realise that thank you, it was a simple example. I should not have done it that way, but it is valid within `MAXVAL` range.

Comment: @chqrlie answer reinstated so OP can see, but not correct.

Answer (score -1):

Since you want to stay with brute force, I am responding with that context.  You can do an increasing sort your detected triplet into a temp array of 3 ints, before storing it in the res.  When a new triplet is detected, sort it and insert that into the temp array, compare the temp array with the arrays stored in your res array to detect a duplicate set and if duplicate continue.

ie. compare res[0][0], res[0][1], res[0][2] with the temp[0], temp[1], temp[2]and detect the duplicates for every triplet that exists in res. And since every res row is sorted, it should be easy to detect duplicates by comparing position to position.

let us say res after a few rounds looks as follows:

-2 1 1

-3 1 2

-7 3 4

and if a new triplet detected is say [4, 3, -7], in temp it will be [-7, 3, 4] and when we loop through res and compare, duplicate will be detected.

To sort num[i], num[j], num[k] you could do the following (again staying in your brute force context):

```
if ((num[i] > num[j])) 
{
    /* Compare the first two numbers in num triplet */
    temp[0] = num[j];
    temp[1] = num[i];
}
else
{
    temp[0] = num[i];
    temp[1] = num[j];
}

//now compare the third number num[k]
if (num[k] < temp[0])
{
    /* num[k] is the smallest number, shift the temp array to the right */
    temp[2] = temp[1];
    temp[1] = temp[0];
    temp[0] = num[k]; /* Add the third number in the beginning of temp array */
}
else
if (num[k] >= temp[1])
{
    /* num[k] is the shortest number, no shifting needed */
    temp[2] = num[k]; /* Add the number num[k] to the end of temp array */
}
else 
{
    /* num[k] is in the middle, shift temp[1] to the right and insert num[k] */
    temp[2] = temp [1]; /* Shift the last number in temp[k] */
    temp[1] = num[k];   /* Overwrite temp[1] with the new number in num[k] which will put num[k] in the middle */
}
```

I haven't tested this code yet.